# How can I properly set the cache directory for ImageResizer on an Azure WebRole?

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, imageresizer

ImageResizer's DiskCache plugin works fine locally, but when I deploy the WebRole to Azure the deployment partition is too small to cache a meaningful amount of files.

Specifically, the WebRole partition is around 1GB on a small role.  I'd like to point the cache directory to:

1. The "C:" drive (around 200+GB on a small role).
2. An attached drive (any size I specify).

The problem is the write privileges necessary for the WebRole.  Is there a simple workaround for a temp directory, or do I need a PowerShell script to configure ACLs on a virtual directory and attach it to the WebRole's site?

Before I go down that route I'd like to know if anyone has a reasonable workaround for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ServiceDefinition.csdef:

```
<Task commandLine="makevdir.cmd" executionContext="elevated" taskType="background" />
```

Makevdir.cmd:

```
PowerShell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted .\makevdir.ps1 >> "%RoleRoot%\makevdir.txt" 2>&1
EXIT /B %errorlevel%
```

Makevdir.ps1:

```
# Make Virtual Directory for ImageResizer DiskCache plugin (/imagecache) 
Write-Host "makevdir.ps1 starting"

# $ImageCacheDir = $env:temp + "\imagecache"
#
# The TEMP paths are quota limited to ~100MB, so use a hard coded path:
$ImageCacheDir = "C:\Resources\AspNetTemp\imagecache"

Write-Host "ImageCacheDir = $ImageCacheDir"
md -Path $ImageCacheDir

# Set the ACL to allow IIS access to the new directory
$acl = Get-Acl $ImageCacheDir
$identity = "IIS_IUSRS"
$fileSystemRights = "Modify"
$inheritanceFlags = "ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit"
$propagationFlags = "None"
$accessControlType = "Allow"
$rule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule($identity,          $fileSystemRights, $inheritanceFlags, $propagationFlags, $accessControlType)
$acl.SetAccessRule($rule)
Set-Acl $ImageCacheDir $acl

# Get the AppName by appending _Web/ to the RoleInstanceID environmental variable
$AppName = $env:RoleInstanceID + "_Web/"
Write-Host "AppName = $AppName"

# Retry creating the virtual directory every five seconds for a maximum of 20 tries
$tries = 0
& $Env:WinDir\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe add vdir /app.name:$AppName /path:/imagecache /physicalpath:$ImageCacheDir
while (!$? -and $tries -lt 20) {
$tries++
    sleep 5
& $Env:WinDir\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe add vdir /app.name:$AppName /path:/imagecache /physicalpath:$ImageCacheDir
}

Write-Host "makevdir.ps1 exiting"
Exit
```

Comment: The problem with this is that IIS is not set up at start up hence it can't find the site to add the vdir to.  One way around this is to add a custom entry point and override the Add() method and do it in code.

Answer (score 0):

As DiskCache delegates the serving of files to IIS for performance, you will need an IIS virtual folder.

DiskCache can cache/serve files from any virtual folder, regardless of its physical location (although local storage is best - latency is unacceptable).

A temp folder won't work, as both IIS and the ASP.NET runtime user accounts need read/write access, and you definitely want DiskCache to be persistent.

It does sound like you'll need to script the setup for this. I think  a lot of people could benefit from such a script, if you can share it when it's done. [Here's how to script an IIS virtual folder](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771804%28v=ws.10%29.aspx).

Comment: I've posted a solution that is far from elegant but does work.  When I get more time I'll try to find a more universal solution and edit my answer.